# Embedding and diffeomorphisms

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

What are the differences between an embedding and a diffeomorphism? Examples and extreme cases would be great.

Answer (score 3):

An embedding is a diffeomorphism onto its image, so the only difference between an embedding and a diffeomorphism is that an embedding may not be surjective, that is all.

For example, $(s,t)\mapsto (s\cos(t),s\sin(t),t)$ is an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not a diffeomorphism.